# external file for initialising objects in flash as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I 'm new in AS3 programming with classes and for my first time I 'm working on a game only with classes. My problem is that I have a bunch of objects to initiate, and I don't want this to be done in my Document Class, but I don't know if I can use another file, and how, to do all this in there. My code (document class) is :

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;

    public class Ingredient_game extends MovieClip {

        //variables
        var allFoods:Array;


        //functions
        public function Ingredient_game() {
            // constructor code
            //add an event listener to update position
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveOnEscalator);
            //initialise allFoods array
            allFoods = new Array();
            var mc1:MovieClip = new carrot();
            var mc2:MovieClip = new lemon();
            var mc3:MovieClip = new potato();
            var mc4:MovieClip = new tomato();
            var mc5:MovieClip = new cereals();
            var mc6:MovieClip = new milk();
            var mc7:MovieClip = new yoghurt();
            var mc8:MovieClip = new apple();
            var mc9:MovieClip = new bananas();
            var mc10:MovieClip = new grapes();
            var mc11:MovieClip = new orange();
            var mc12:MovieClip = new pear();
            var mc13:MovieClip = new strawberry();
            var mc14:MovieClip = new watermelon();

            allFoods.push(mc1);
            allFoods.push(mc2);
            allFoods.push(mc3);
            allFoods.push(mc4);
            allFoods.push(mc5);
            allFoods.push(mc6);
            allFoods.push(mc7);
            allFoods.push(mc8);
            allFoods.push(mc9);
            allFoods.push(mc10);
            allFoods.push(mc11);
            allFoods.push(mc12);
            allFoods.push(mc13);
            allFoods.push(mc14);

            for( var i = 0; i < allFoods.length; i++ ){
                var newx:Number = 800+100*i;
                allFoods[i].initialisePosition(newx, 500);
                addChild(allFoods[i]);
            }

        }

        function moveOnEscalator(e:Event):void{
            for( var i = 0; i < allFoods.length; i++ ){

                if( allFoods[i].x >= 0 ){
                    allFoods[i].x -= 5;
                }
                else{
                    allFoods[i].x = allFoods.length*100;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

What I need exactly is put in another file the code from `var mc1` to `allFoods.push(mc14);` somewhere else! Any idea how??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a utility class:

```
package
{

    public class UtilityClass
    {

        public function buildMCs():Array
        {
            var result:Array = new Array();
            result.push(new carrot());
            result.push(new lemon());
            result.push(new potato());
            result.push(new tomato());
            result.push(new cereals());
            result.push(new milk());
            result.push(new yoghurt());
            result.push(new apple());
            result.push(new bananas());
            result.push(new grapes());
            result.push(new orange());
            result.push(new pear());
            result.push(new strawberry());
            result.push(new watermelon());
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

And then amend your function to call buildMCs():

```
public function Ingredient_game()
{
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveOnEscalator);

    //create instance of utility class
    var builder:UtilityClass = new UtilityClass();
    //call buildMCs to populate array
    allFoods = builder.buildMCs();

    for (var i = 0; i < allFoods.length; i++ )
    {
        var newx:Number = 800+100*i;
        allFoods[i].initialisePosition(newx, 500);
        addChild(allFoods[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Lee. I thought that this was the way to do, but I didn't know how to write the code! Plus you saved me a lot of code!